# Salesforce Fingerprint API

Tags: api

What is fingerprint API shared by salesforce.

In `Workbench` > `Rest Explorer` I can see an API:

> /services/data/v40.0/fingerprint

How does it work, any document reference will be helpful.

Comment: Presumably related to [Log In Password-Free with Lightning Login](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter17/release-notes/rn_security_auth_lightning_login.htm).

Comment: I noticed the same and looking for an answer